# Are there any existing code viewer components for Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm looking for a code viewer component, similar to what Angular Material uses for their examples, but I haven't had any luck finding one so far.

Below is an example of what Angular Material uses.
https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview

[image: Here is an example]

I attempted to grab the source code the for Angular Material component, but there are so many scripts involved it would take a while to figure out exactly all that is required.

Comment: Hi @Darcy the slide togle is the component you see in your screenshot in the bottom, the "on/off" switch. What are you looking for? A component to show a formatted code as html, ts and css?

Comment: @Kalamarico he is looking for a code viewer. What are you on about?

Comment: @AvinKavish on the same, a code prettier. I have used before ngx-highlightjs or codemirror

Comment: Thanks, I looked at `primeng` and `ngx-highlight-js`. I ended up going with `ngx-highlight-js` since I'm using Angular Material and only need a code highlighter.